# Why can't I add elements to this list? (Object oriented programming in python)

Tags: python, oop

Hi everyone I am currently creating a student class to record down exam results and find the average score. Here's the code I have right now:

```
class Student:
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.all_grades = []
        
    def add_exam(self, newest_grade):
        self.newest_grade = newest_grade
        self.all_grades = self.all_grades.append(newest_grade)
              
    def get_mean(self):
        self.average = sum(self.all_grades)/len(self.all_grades)

Josh = Student()
Josh.add_exam(72)
```

However, when I try to put print(Josh.all_grades), it doesn't return anything and type(Josh.all_grades) returns a none type.

I am really lost and I don't understand why it doesn't return [72]

Comment: `self.all_grades = self.all_grades.append(newest_grade)` append doesn't return anything, change it to `self.all_grades.append(newest_grade)`

Answer (score 1):

You've to just type `self.all_grades.append(newest_grade)` instead of typing `self.all_grades=self.all_grades.append(newest_grade)`. When you type `append()`, it adds element to list. But it returns `None`. So when you type `<list_variable>.append(<element>)` it adds the element, but when you type `<list_variable>=<list_variable>.append(<element>)` then the value of whole list is now `None`